# Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that $n(n + 1)(n + 2)(n + 3)$ cannot be a square or a cube.

Tags: number-theory

For the expression cannot be a square, there is an answer here. [Prove that $ \sqrt{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)+1} $ is always a natural number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007303/prove-that-sqrtnn1n2n31-is-always-a-natural-number)

I am trying to prove it cannot be a cube.
There is a conclusion that every cube could be written as the difference of two squared, i.e.
$r^3$ = $p^2$ - $q^2$, where $p = r(r+1)/2$ and $q = r(r-1)/2$.

Therefore I think the conclusion holds if $n(n + 1)(n + 2)(n + 3)$ could not be expressed as the difference of two squared but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Well, by the Catalan conjecture, now [Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), there can't be any positive consecutive cubes and squares other than $8,9$ so the old argument works here as well.  Of course there may well be a simpler argument in this particular case.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for point.I read the question as $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)+1$ cannot be a perfect cube. I thought about editing the answer, but there are a lot of articles online for the solution of $m^3-n^2=1$.  So basically the asker can read it himself.  Regardless of NN2's answer, there are different proofs for $m^3-n^2=1.$

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1/ $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ can't be a square number**

Denote $x = \sqrt{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
x^2 &= n(n+3)(n+1)(n+2) \\
&= (n^2+3n)(n^2+3n+2)\\
&= (n^2+3n+1)^2 -1
\end{align}
$$

It's easy to notice that
$$(n^2+3n)^2 <(n^2+3n+1)^2 -1 <(n^2+3n+1)^2$$
$$\implies n^2+3n < x <n^2+3n+1 \tag{1}$$
From $(1)$ we deduce that $x$ can't be a natural number so $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ can't be a square number.

**2/ $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$  can't be a cube number**

Denote $x = \sqrt[3]{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$ and $y = n^2 +3n+1$ suppose $x \in \Bbb N+$. We have

$$x^3 = (n^2+3n+1)^2 -1 \implies x^3= y^2-1 \tag{2}$$

This diophantine equation $(2)$ [is not trivial](https://mathoverflow.net/q/39561/62193). An elementary proof of the problem can be found in the paper [THE DIOPHANTINE EQUATIONS x3=Ny2±1](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-pdf/42/1/27/4415873/42-1-27.pdf) of (J. H. E. Cohn, 1991) (or this [link](https://sci-hub.st/https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/42.1.27)) according to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/39564/62193) and the unique solution of $(2)$ is $(x,y) =(2,3)$.

However, there doesn't exist $n \in \Bbb N^+$ such that $n^3+3n+1 = 3$.

Hence, $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$  can't be a cube number.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I may need to read the proof of the equation having unique solution of (2,3)

Comment: @RunzeLi I added a second link for the paper so you could read it freely. If you can't access it, use TOR as browser.